# On infinitely many solutions of a nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I have a problem with showing that a given nonlinear ODE has infinitely many solutions. I would be glad if someone can come up with any examples (and its proof) related to this problem.

I would then study this example to understand this concept and apply to mine. I would be glad if there are any references where I can get one or two of such problems and their solutions.

I have read "existence and uniqueness" chapters in a number of textbooks about nonlinear ODEs, but most only give theorems and no applications or exercises to study.

Comment: Do you really mean the ODE has infinitely many solutions (e.g. one for each initial condition), or that an initial value problem has infinitely many solutions?

Comment: The first question was to show that the given ODE has infinitely many solutions (No Initial condition was given). The the next was to define interval of existence for the solution x(a)=0. But my problem lies in the first part. Just to show that the given ODE has infinitely many Solutions..

Answer (score 1):

Consider any ODE that satisfies the standard existence and uniqueness theorem in some
rectangle $a < x < b$, $c < y < d$.  Pick some $x_0 \in (a,b)$.  For each $y_0 \in (c,d)$, the existence and uniqueness theorem says there is a unique solution 
satisfying the initial condition $y(x_0) = y_0$, defined on some interval
containing $x_0$.  There are infinitely many possible $y_0$, so that's infinitely many solutions right there.

Comment: Please is there any particular example that can be used to buttress this point?

Comment: Sure.  Try $y' = y^2$.